# Is the sentence below correct?

Tags: grammar

Is the sentence below correct? Any ambiguity?

> I conclude that whether the internet supports everyone to get together and keep company or not, depends on why and how each one of us uses it.

Should a comma needed before 'or not' ? Any other punctuation mistakes?
Also is it a good sentence? (I mean does the sentence seem long or difficult to understand?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the gerund after "support". "...supports everyone getting together and keeping company..."

Answer (score 1):

It's not ambiguous. It's pretty good, but it could be made easier to follow.

Personally I don't see the need for the comma you have there.

In a way the use of "or not" is redundant after using "whether". For example:

> "I'm going to see whether it's raining (or not)"

"or not" is not necessarily needed. However it's often added. Just letting you know about this. How about bringing "or not" all the way back to "whether", as in:

> I conclude that whether ***or not*** the internet supports everyone to get
>   together and keep company depends on why and how each one of us uses
>   it.

I think this is a bit better. Another change we can make, which isn't necessary, is to swap "why and how" around. As you can see in this chart it's much more common and natural to say "how and why" instead of the other way around:

[How and why vs why and how](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=why%20and%20how%2C%20how%20and%20why&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhy%20and%20how%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chow%20and%20why%3B%2Cc0)

So we'll swap "why and how", no problem. Since you say "each one of us" at the end of the sentence, how about if we replace "everyone" with "us all", this simplifies it in a couple of places.

> I conclude that whether or not the internet supports ***us all*** to get
>   together and keep company depends on how and why ***we each use it***.

Finally, and this is optional again (everything is optional), could "get together and keep company" be replaced with something shorter? How about "helps bring us all together"?

> I conclude that whether or not the internet helps bring us all together depends on how and why we each use it.

And you could keep on going... I realise the changes have resulted in something not exactly the same as your original, that's why I say every example I give is optional, it's up to you. You can have "helps us all connect/interact/socialise", whatever you want.

Also, it seems to me that the initial part of the sentence of the sentence should use the future tense, because you're talking about what the internet might do for us in the future. This isn't strictly necessary, another optional thing:

> I conclude that whether or not the internet ***will help*** bring us all
>   together depends on how and why we each use it.